# Reasons of 500 internal server error in php

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to upload the large image(1 MB) files on server using php code but it is
showing the 500 internal server error it is only uploading up to 128 KB.
Even though i have checked all the required setting of my server 
all settings are correct i am not getting how to trace this error.Is
there any other setting which i don't know so please help me to find out or
if all settings is fine then please help me trace out this 500 internal server error.

**Settings which i have already verified.**

```
memory_limit 90M
post_max_size 64M
upload_max_filesize 64M
FcgidMaxRequestLen 104857600
```

**Below is the error:**

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@domain.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: You need to look at your actual error logs to find what the issue is

Comment: Actually i don't have access of error logs.But here i am correct means all the settings are fine which i have mention above.can you please guide me where i can find the actual path of error logs so that i can ask to server administrator person.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors' ,1)` put this line at the start of your page and check what error are you getting?

Comment: No prakash it is not showing any kind of error except 500 internal server error please contact the server administrator.

Comment: As @Darren mentioned, you need to take a look at your error log. There are a lot of reasons maybe one of them could be a PHP error (e.g. syntax) in a disable errors environment.

Comment: You should set `display_errors=1` in php.ini or htaccess, rather than in the code, because if its in the code some errors may not be shown, eg if they occur before the `ini_set()` line is run. Also set `error_reporting` to show all errors.

Comment: Check all your code for syntax errors by running `php -l filename.php` for each PHP file in your system.

Answer (score 2):

Use two lines at the top of the page to display errors

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
```